# Subprocess.poll() falsely returns a value

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

**test1.py:**

```
process = Popen(["python","test2.py"])
time.sleep(3)

alive = process.poll()
if alive is None:
    print "Still running"
else:
    print "Not running\r\n"
    print "%r" % alive
```

**test1.py Output:**

`Not running`
`2`

**test2.py:**

```
time.sleep(30)
print "done"
```

What is going on? Shouldn't this return "Still running"?

---

Because of a contradicting result here's the full test1.py code:

```
import cStringIO
import os
import cgi
import time
from subprocess import Popen

def application(environ, start_response):
    headers = []
    headers.append(('Content-Type', 'text/plain'))
    write = start_response('200 OK', headers)

    input = environ['wsgi.input']
    output = cStringIO.StringIO()

    process = Popen(["python","test2.py"])
    time.sleep(3)

    alive = process.poll()
    if alive is None:
        print >> output, "Still running"
    else:
        print >> output, "Not running\r\n"
        print >> output, "%r" % alive

    output.write(input.read(int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', '0'))))
    return [output.getvalue()]
```

---

**Updated test1.py:**

```
process = Popen(["python","C:/wamp/www/python/popen/test2.py"], shell=True)
    time.sleep(5)

    alive = process.poll()
    if alive is None:
        #print >> output, "%r" % alive
        print >> output, "Still running"
    else:
        print >> output, "Not running"
        print >> output, "%r" % alive
        print >> output, "Current working dir : %s" % os.getcwd()
        print >> output, os.strerror(0)
```

**Updated Output:**

`Not running`
`0`
`Current working dir : C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22`
`No error`

Comment: Its working fine for me. My output is `Still running`.

Comment: da fuq... well then I have a new problem. Any ideas? I'll post more code... BTW I thought it was weird, because no where in my searches did I find a "2" as a result for poll().

Comment: Same result with RanRag, I got "Still running" as well.

Comment: What OS, build, version etc.?

Comment: Are you running the process through the shell environment or directly?  That may have something to do with it

Comment: @pythonm windows, Python 2.7.3, 64bit, wamp server

Comment: @primehunter326 not sure how to tell. I've tried both `Popen(["python","C:/wamp/www/python/popen/test2.py"])` and `Popen(["python","C:/wamp/www/python/popen/test2.py"], shell=True)`

Comment: Even though `shell=False` is the default, try explicitly setting it in the constructor.  I'm not as familiar with the windows environment so I'm not sure exactly what the difference would be.  I think your issue is a combination of Windows specific handling of certain operations and some output (particularly STDERR) getting sent somewhere.  Try capturing STDERR of the subprocess in your python code and printing it to STDOUT when the subprocess terminates, though if it's now giving exit code 0 then there shouldn't be anything...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If Popen() cannot find test2.py, it produces the error "No such file or directory", with errno 2. This error number is returned by poll(). Since you seem to be running this script through wsgi, something seems to be gulping your stderr and you don't see the error message:

```
$ cat test1.py
from subprocess import Popen
import time

process = Popen(["python","doesnotexist.py"])
time.sleep(3)

alive = process.poll()
if alive is None:
    print "Still running"
else:
    print "Not running\r\n"
    print "%r" % alive
$ python test1.py 
python: can't open file 'doesnotexist.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Not running

2
```

Now, the issue is probably because your current working directory of your script is not set to the script's directory by the front end server, try printing os.getcwd() to see if it's what you're expecting.

Comment: I was going to point out that `test2.py` does not seem to import the `time` module; while that may be an error as well, this is the more immediate cause of your problem.

Comment: +1, beat me to typing this out. If you're trying to find what an exit code is, you can try the ``os.strerror()`` function to see if it gives a meaningful message: ``>> import os >> os.strerror(2)`` gives the message ``'No such file or directory'``.

Comment: tried `http://localhost:1234/python/popen/test2.py` and `C:\wamp\www\python\popen\test2.py` same error...

Comment: @Rawr: since you're on Windows, do you double backslash escape your path strings? Alternatively, you can use forward slash instead of backslash to avoid string escaping issues, most Windows functions that accepts path can use forward slash as well as backward slash as path separator. btw, did you check your getcwd()?

Comment: Current working dir : C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22 but the cwd shouldn't matter if I point directly to the file, right?

Comment: Whoa, I used `C:/wamp/www/python/popen/test2.py` and now I'm getting 0 as the result. but it's still saying not running...

Comment: @Rawr: did you have `import time` on test2.py?

Comment: Have you run `test2.py` from a command prompt to make sure it does what you expect it to do?

Comment: LieRyan Yep @primehunter326 Yea I ran it on the browser, waits 30 and then prints done

Comment: **Problem solved:** not sure why but I made test2.py finish after sleep(5) and i returned poll() in test1.py every second and I get "None" for the first second, and then 0 afterwards. So I'm guessing the timing is off, but it works so hurray

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html)

An exit status of 2 indicates an issue with the shell executing the command.  Have you tried running `test2.py` directly in the shell to verify there aren't issues with it?  As Lie pointed out it could be that the shell can't find the file you're trying to execute, though there could be another issue causing it to break.